# Connecting to external database using java

Tags: java, jdbc, aix, jtds

I have a java program that connects to a MS SQL database.  The program works perfectly when running through eclipse however I get an error when I run it through AIX:

java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: A remote host refused an attempted connect operation.

I am using jtds to connect:

```
String connectionString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+dropez_ip_address+"/"+dropez_db_name;
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement stmt = null;

try{

    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dropez_db_username, dropez_db_password);

    stmt = conn.createStatement();
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: Check whether username password pair is correct or not. And make sure sql server is running on the system. Also check the port number.

Comment: Also check if you have permissions to access database remotely (it is common practice to deny remote access by default)

Comment: the connection worked from windows, so i assume i have permission, it just wont work from AIX

Answer (score 1):

From [jTDS documentation](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#connectionRefused):

> Why do I get java.sql.SQLException: "Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect" when trying to get a connection?
>
> The "Connection refused" exception is thrown by jTDS when it is unable to connect to the server. There may be a number of reasons why this could happen:
>
> - The server name is misspelled or the port number is incorrect.
> - SQL Server is not configured to use TCP/IP. Either enable TCP/IP from SQL Server's Network Utility app or have jTDS connect via named pipes (see the URL format for information on how to do this).
> - There is a firewall blocking port 1433 on the server.
>
> To check whether TCP/IP is enabled and the port is not blocked you can use "telnet  1433". Until telnet doesn't connect, jTDS won't either. If you can't figure out why, ask your network administrator for help.

My bet is your firewall does not allow the AIX host to connect.

Comment: i tried "telnet _ipaddress_" and got "telnet: connect: A remote host refused an attempted connect operation."

Comment: @Mike, you should test with `telnet ipaddress port`, by default `telnet` uses port 23. The default SQL Server port is 1433.

Comment: a `ping ipaddress` gets a response

Comment: `ping` proves `ICMP` is permitted by firewal and the server is reachable. Doesn't tell anything about other ports.

Comment: `telnet ipaddress port`  gives the 'telnet: connect: A remote host refused an attempted connect operation.' error

Comment: Check with your network admin to see if there are any firewall restrictions